# How to pass state data to another webpage through react router link?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props, react-component

I am building an issue tracker app that is based on react/django. I am trying to pass projects, a state variable that is an array of project objects, to manageusers so that I can have access to the name of the project in manageusers. The reason behind this is so that I can use that project name to find the project associated with it, and assign users to the project. I am using a state object to pass projects to a link, but when I try to load the manageusers webpage it is stating that state is undefined. Keep in mind the projects data from the django backend is coming in fine, I am just trying to get that data onto manageusers.

**Project**

**project.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Grid, TextField, Button, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Link,
    Route,
    Switch,
  } from 'react-router-dom';

const project = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [description, setDescription] = useState();
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  const post = () => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,  
        description: description,
      }),
    };
    fetch("/api/newProject",requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) =>{
       
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/manageprojects")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) =>{
        setProjects(data)
    })
  }, [])

      return (
        <div>
          <body>
              <form action="#" method="POST">
                <TextField onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                <br>
                </br>
                <TextField onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}> </TextField>
                <br>
                </br>
                <Button onClick={() => post()}> Create New Project </Button>
              </form>
          </body>
          <div>
                {projects && projects.map(project => (
                    <Grid item xs={3}>
                        <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
                            <h5> {project.name} </h5>
                            <h5> {project.description} </h5>
                        </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
          </div>
          <Link to={{
            pathname: '/manageusers',
            state: { 
                projects: projects
            }
          }}>Manage Users
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
  }
 


export default project;
```

**Manage Users**

**a portion of manageusers.js**

```
const Name = (props) => {
    const {projects} = props.location.state;
    console.log(projects.name);
}   
      return (
          <div>
            <Select 
                value={selectedValue}
                options={roles}
                onChange={handleChange}
                isOptionDisabled={option => option.isDisabled}
            />
            <div class="ex1">
                {role && role.map(roles => (
                        <Grid item xs={3}>
                            <Typography component="h5" variant="h5">
                                <h5> {roles.username} </h5>
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                ))}
            </div>
            <Name/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using React Router link,

what you need is a global store, such as Redux or Mobx. That way you can update the state with relevant data and retrieve them on the new page.

If you need a workaround, you could use history.pushState()

Basically you can push to your location and with it a state.

And on the next page, which is MyComp in this case, you could use history.state to retrieve the pushed data.

Comment: Oh ok I'll definitely look into Redux or Mobx. I'll prob try history.pushState() as well. Thank you for the help!